# Find intersection of two fit

Tags: c#, math.net

I use CubicSpline function from math.net to fit a series of data. for example this.

```
    double[] x8 = { 2.25, 2.65, 3.12, 3.56, 3.95, 4.32, 4.59, 4.78 };
    double[] y8 = { 124, 117, 108, 95, 79, 64, 48.5, 36 };
    CubicSpline CSpline = CubicSpline.InterpolateNatural(x8, y8);
```

I have another sets of point which I want to use Polynomial to fit. for example this:

```
    double[] x9 = {0, 4,-4};
    double[] y9 = { 0, 50,50 };
    double[] p = Fit.Polynomial(x9, y9, 2);
```

Now I want to find the intersection of these fits and show it on the chart. Can you please help me how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely mathematical question, and quite impossilbe if your polynomal has certain properties that make it very hard to find the intersection. I suggest you use cubic-splines for both curves and simply adjust the Parameters to fit your needs, because calculating the intersection of two cubic funtions precisely is possible. If you still want to use the polinomial your best bet is something like the Newton Approximation for Zero of the difference oft he two funtions.

Newton method:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Cubic intersection Code snipped (in c++ but you can easily translate):
http://web.archive.org/web/20130613230901/http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pang/160/f98/Gems/GemsIV/curve_isect/Bezier.cc